# Wordpress menu: How to make www.link.com/#name never contain current_page_item class?

Tags: customization, menus, css

I am using the wordpress menus on a website, but the problem is that one of the links on that menu is www.homepage.com/#order

So, when I am on the homepage, both "home" and "order" links on the menu contain the class current_page_item, which with my css it makes them appear both as the active button.

How can I make it so the #order link never contains that the current_page_item class?

Here's a screenshot of how the menu looks when visiting the homepage and how I set it up on the admin panel:

http://img87.imageshack.us/img87/7666/screenshotrq.png

On the firebug panel you can see that both www.homepage.com and www.homepage.com/#order menu links contain the current_page_item class.

This is the php code I am using to display the menus:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'menu' => 'Top Menu',
     'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
     'container_class' => ' '
);
wp_nav_menu($args); 
?>
```

Comment: @Rockxy: Are you using the new "Menus" of WordPress 3.0? (Under *Appearance* => *Menus*?) When I look at the code I see the classes `current-menu-item` and `current_page_item`, but not `current-page`, and I can't replicate this situation (only one link "lights up" for me). Can you edit your question to include a screenshot of the admin area and the front side? (Use `@Jan` if you reply to me in a comment and I get a notification)

Comment: @Jan Fabry: Yes, I've used the wp3 menus from Appearance => Menus, and you are right current_page doesn't exist, I made a mistake, it's current_page_item the class that cause the link to be "active". I used firebug to see the css and underscores doesn't show up clearly there, so I though it had two classes (current_page and item). I am going to edit the question and show a screenshot of how the menu looks.

Comment: @Jan or @Jan Fabry send the notification? I hope it works :P

Comment: Ah, it only happens when I use the full URL, not when I just use `/` or `/#order` for the link. But I see One Trick Pony already solved it, so that's great! [The full rules for `@username` replies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) are complicated, just remember that the first name you mention with at least three characters will get a notification. So `@Roc` would also work for you (unless someone else named `Roc` also participated in the discussion). For me it's easy, both `@Jan` and `@JanFabry` would work (you must leave out spaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a bit hacky, but it works:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'remove_some_menu_classes', 420 ,3);
function remove_some_menu_classes($classes, $item, $args){
  if(strpos($item->url, '#order') !== false)
    // in the 2nd array put the classes you want removed
    return array_diff($classes, array('current_page_item', 'current-menu-item'));

  return $classes;
}
```

Comment: use `#` instead of `#order` to remove these classes from any links containing # anchors...

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. I shoudl add it on /mytheme/functions.php right?

Comment: yeah. or put that in a .php file inside `wp-content/mu-plugins`